# illustrator compound paths: how can I make the white shapes transparent?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pathfinder

I'm trying to handle an Illustrator compound path:

- a scanned signature on a white paper
- vectorised with the image trace panel
- as you can see in the image, the white shapes in the black mother shape needs to be subtracted from the "mother shape" which is now an compound path
- when I try to release the compound path I get the error: "can't ungroup the objects".

How can I make the white shapes transparent?

[image: screenshot]

what happens after deleting the white shape twice with the white arow:
[image: after shape deletion with direct select tool]

what happens after using the "select-all" + pathfinder "merge" button:
[image]

full scene with layers:
[image]

EDIT/SOLUTION:
The merge function from the pathfinder did not solve the problem, it only made the white holes black. Then I just started over completely and did the trace again from the jpg, this time I made sure I selected the: "Ignore White" option checkbox. It worked perfectly. But still no idea how I need to cut out shapes from a compound path.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. In your image trace settings, hit *Advanced* and choose the option "Ignore white".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Select All** (`Select > Select All`)
- Click the **Merge** button on the **Pathfinder Panel**
- Click ONE white shape with the **Direct Selection Tool** (White arrow)
- Choose `Select > Same > Fill & Stroke` from the menu
- Hit the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key

When tracing, if you don't tick the `Ignore white` option, white-filled shapes get created for counters. In 99.99% of these instances you can merely delete the white shapes and *under* them is *actually* the compound path (with proper transparent counters).

---

I took your first image, added a white background and saved it as a jpg...

[image]

Opened that in Illustrator CS6 and Image Traced with `Ignore White` ticked. Then **expanded the trace**, Direct Selection Tool and dragged to select the outer rectangle, `Select > Same > Fill & Stroke`, hit <kbd>Delete</kbd>..

Result.. perfectly fine compound shape...

[image]

Comment: well I've tried that, it works ro get the while-filled shapes get deleted, but still no transparency... when i select the white-fill again and hit delete I get this... (see second image in my edited post...)

Comment: @Kleajmp "white filled shapes again" -- meaning you already deleted them once? You should have included that in the question. In that case, Select all and then click the **Merge** button on the **Pathfinder Panel**... then follow the steps above in this answer. - Something is "off" in your tracing settings. This should be straightforward. I'd wager you have it set to stack objects (or Adobe's changed the defaults)

Comment: wow this "Shape Builder Tool" is totally new to me... seems like I cannot use it (cursor shows a forbidden icon) can we chat for a moment?

Comment: You must have the art selected before the Shape Builder tool can be used... in any event, I edited that comment @Kleajmp with an easier method.. `:)`

Comment: so many years I used Illustrator... but I cannot make it work. Can you please write my a step by step instruction? don't understand this tool :-°] I own you!

Comment: "own me"??? I've edited my answer with a step-by-step process.

Comment: I mean thank you a lot for helping me, but where did you put the step-by-step? I've edited my post with extra screenshots...

Comment: This answer has all the steps necessary.

Comment: ok I guess I'll take a look at it tomorrow with a fresh head, cause I don't get it now, thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: The merge function from the pathfinder did not solve the problem, it only made the white holes black. Then I just started over completely and did the trace again from the jpg, this time I made sure I selected the: "Ignore White" option checkbox. It worked perfectly. But still no idea how I need to cut out shapes from a compound path.

Comment: Not sure why it wouldn't' work for you. I've done this more times than I could possibly count and these steps are pretty much always the same steps resulting in a proper final compound shape.

Comment: Yeah, I don't understand it ether, I used the trace tool so many times before, without any issues. No other possibility I did something wrong. But after all, it's solved now. So thanks again for your time and effort.